# Awesome CV - How to modify CV entry to hold a description, headings and two bulleted lists

Tags: awesome-cv

I am trying to learn Latex, but struggling to achieve what I want.

I want to learn Latex using the awesome-cv template and customizing it.

I want to achieve this:

[image]

```
So I tried to modify the template:


%---------------------------------------------------------
\cventry
{Manager, XYZ} % Job title
{ZYX} % Organization
{Foo} % Location
{Apr 2016 - Present} % Date(s)
{
General description of work  

Career:
 \begin{cvitems} % Description(s) of tasks/responsibilities    
            \item {Manager: Jan 2017 - now}
            \item {Senior Consultant: Apr 2016 - Jan 2017}
  \end{cvitems}
Projects:
 \begin{cvitems} % Description(s) of tasks/responsibilities    
            \item {IFRS 9}
            \item {BI}
            \item {Back-office}
  \end{cvitems}
}
\end{cventries}
```

The result is this:

[image]

I know that I need to modify this part, but I don't know what to do:

```
\newcommand*{\cventry}[5]{%
  \vspace{-2.0mm}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} L{\textwidth - 4.5cm} R{4.5cm}}
    \ifempty{#2#3}
      {\entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
      {\entrytitlestyle{#2} & \entrylocationstyle{#3} \\
      \entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
    \multicolumn{2}{L{\textwidth}}{\descriptionstyle{#5}}
  \end{tabular*}%
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command to define an entry of cv information requires five parameters.

```
\cventry{<position>}{<title>}{<location>}{<date>}{<description>}
```

Some may be empty. Having two "sections" under the same company requires having to apply it twice; the second time without the name and location of the company.

```
\cvsection{Profesional Experience}

\begin{cventries}
\cventry
{Career:} % Job title
{ZYX} % Organization
{Foo} % Location
{Apr 2016 - Present} % Date(s)
{%
\begin{cvitems} % Description(s) of tasks/responsibilities    
    \item {Manager: Jan 2017 - now}
    \item {Senior Consultant: Apr 2016 - Jan 2017}
\end{cvitems}
}

\cventry
{Projects:} % Job title
{} % leave empty
{} % leave empty
{Apr 2016 - Present} % Date(s)
{%
\begin{cvitems} % Description(s) of tasks/responsibilities    
            \item {IFRS 9}
            \item {BI}
            \item {Back-office}
\end{cvitems}
}

\end{cventries}
```

[image: a]

IMHO it's very hard to learn LaTeX trying to modify someone else's uncommented code. Why don't you start using LaTeX commands to produce a document yourself? You may be trying to emulate the `awesome-cv` main features: layout, fonts, colors, ... Start with the `article` class step by step.